# Converting SparkR predictions to readable format (number or string)

Tags: r, sparkr

I'm using Spark with R to create a RandomForest model (spark.randomForest) and then predict the labels (classification) for the testing data. The issue I have is that I not only need the 'prediction' column with its label/prediction, but I also need the 'probability' column to be able to export/save that to a file, 'csv' would be great, but in a readable format. The 'probability' column seems to be, from what I've read, an S4 vector and I've been unable to convert that to any readable double/string so far. The resulting data frame is, of course, a Spark DataFrame.

I'm primarily using the 'SparkR' library due to project restrictions.

Could anybody point me in the right direction? TIA.

Comment: Just did. Sorry about that. Thanks.

Comment: Can you print a row of the probability column?  According to this https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/R/spark.randomForest.html  it should be a list and you could then select the element from the list.

Comment: Yes, I did the following:
`p <- SparkR::select(predictions, "date", "id", "probability", "prediction")`
`out <- print(p)`
and got something like this:
`date                 id                            probability  prediction`
`1 2016-10-02  700114643 <environment: 0x2e257a8>               0`.
My issue is with the "environment..." portion. I'd like to be able to work with the floating numbers, like what you get if you do a `showDF(x)` on the SparkDataFrame.
Sorry for the ugly formatting in the comment.