# Accessing probabiliy object column in random forest sparkR

Tags: r, sparkr

In SparkR, i have something like this

```
rf <- spark.randomForest(train, formula, type = "classification")
pred <- predict(rf,test)
```

executing

```
head(pred)
```

the output is what you can see in the image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I71J5.png)

[Converting SparkR predictions to readable format (number or string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47269848/converting-sparkr-predictions-to-readable-format-number-or-string#)

How can i get the value of the probability?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call a Java Method called `values` for each object using the function `sparkR.callJMethod`.

```
t(sapply(collect(select(pred, "probability"))$probability, 
         FUN = function(x) sparkR.callJMethod(x, "values")))
```

Here is a full example using Iris dataset. The target value is `Species` which has 3 levels and there is a total number of 150 data points.

```
df <- createDataFrame(iris)
model <- spark.randomForest(df, Species ~ ., type = "classification")
summary(model)

predictions <- predict(model, df)

local_prob <- collect(select(predictions, "probability"))$probability

t(sapply(local_prob, FUN = function(x) sparkR.callJMethod(x, "values")))
```

Note that the predictions are collected and if the dataset is big, you may run out of memory. If so, you can used `head` instead.

Truncated output:

```
       [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
  [1,] 0           0           1   
  [2,] 0           0           1   
  [3,] 0           0           1   
...  
[148,] 0           1           0   
[149,] 0.05        0.95        0   
[150,] 0.01805556  0.9819444   0
```